# How to show the past 24 months from now?

Tags: php

I need to write a simple loop routine to show 24 months back starting with today's month. How would I do that?

```
$start = date(M) - 24;
$end = date(M);

foreach() {
    echo ''; // Dec, Jan...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++) {
    echo date("M", strtotime("-$i months")) . "\n";
}
```

**Result**

```
Feb
Jan
Dec
Nov
Oct
Sep
Aug
Jul
Jun
May
Apr
Mar
Feb
Jan
Dec
Nov
Oct
Sep
Aug
Jul
Jun
May
Apr
Mar
```

[See a demo](http://codepad.org/KgfJq7bf)

Comment: Perfect. I've changed it to for($i = 23; $i >= 0; $i--) { to output: Jan  Feb Mar... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++) {
    $months[] = date("Y-m%", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months"));
}
```

or
for full textual representation of month you need to pass "F":

```
echo date("y:F:d");
```

for previous month you can use

```
echo date("y:F:d",strtotime("-24 Months"))
```